# Using java.util.HashMap with Hibernate with key as some class and value as ArrayList of objects

Tags: hibernate, annotations, mapping, hashmap

I definitely read most of the posts regarding this on googleand stackoverflow but I am not  getting a clear idea about this.

**Scenario:**

```
public enum UserLicenseType {
    DEMO_LICENSE1,DEMO_LICENSE2
}

@Entity(name = "UserLicense")

public class UserLicense implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private UserLicenseType licenseType;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Permission> permissions;

    // getters and setters...

}

public enum PermissionType {
    DEMO_PERMISSION1,DEMO_PERMISSION2
}

@Entity(name = "Permission")
public class Permission implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private PermissionType permissionType;
}


@Entity(name = "UserProfile")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @CollectionOfElements
    Map<UserLicense, ArrayList<Permission>> permissionForLicense;
}
```

Database table created corresponding **Map{UserLicense, ArrayList{Permission}} permissionForLicense** have three fields

1. UserProfile_Id : type = int
2. element : type = tinyblob
3. permissionForLicense_Key : type = int

**Scenario Ends**

First of all is it possible to use 
    **Map{UserLicense, ArrayList{Permission}}**
 kind of structure.

If yes where am I wrong?

If not, please provide a best object oriented way.